# Cloudflare pages proxy with basic auth

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

Is there a way to write a cloudflare rewrite/proxy similar to netlify as per https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#proxy-to-another-service and adjust the header with basic auth credentials?

For example I would need /api/* to redirect to a WordPress at domain.com/wp-json/* with basic auth headers (ideally not visible to client itself - not sure if this is also possible)